# SDK Manager failed to install 'java.exe' locking directory

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have ran into a curious error when trying to update `Android SDK Tools` to `revision 21` from `revision 20.0.3`. The ADT plug-in updated properly so now I am at a stand still until resolved.

The initial error I got listed `cmd.exe` & `java.exe` as locking the directory, I forced closed `cmd.exe` and got this:

[image]

If I force close `java.exe` then obviously my SDK Manager closes.

SDK Manager Log:

[image]

This is my work computer so I'd really like to avoid any down-time resulting from a reboot, just curious if anyone has come across this issue and been able to resolve.

I have tried closing Eclispe and running SDK Manager from the file directory, same issue, I read that someone had experienced this while having the directory opened so I closed and still, same issue. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Eclipse:**
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

---

**Update:**

Fresh reboot did **NOT** resolve.

Comment: android.bat has the comment `Copy android.bat and its required libs to a temp dir. This avoids locking the tool dir in case the user is trying to update it.` The Android tools are terrible. :(

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I resolved this by copying my `\tools` folder, naming the copy `\toolsCopy`. Then I ran `android.bat` from the `\toolsCopy` folder with Administrator privileges.

Running the SDK manager from `\tools` locked the renaming of the `\tools` directory, for obvious reasons. SMH

Comment: This solved it for me, although I had to add the path to my xcopy.exe file on Windows using the Path command inside a command prompt. Then from within the command prompt, I was able to start android.bat and proceed with the update.

Comment: @Asok I trying this, where do you copy tools to? I tried to my desktop but it didn't recognize any of the files i already had so I tried a copy inside the original folder but I get the same java blocking as before. *EDIT : I solved the problem, I just had to restart my computer after moving the files. All you do is create the copy in the original directory and run it from there.

Comment: How did the android team come with this fault upgrade strategy, what a shame!

Comment: Before running android.bat from \toolsCopy . Please stop cmd.exe and java.exe using task manager and then run android.bat

Answer (score 9):

It work for me after long search

1. Close the sdk manager and eclipse.
2. Go to the folder where you have stored your adt.
3. In that adt folder you'll find a folder known as tools.
4. Make a copy  of the contents of that folder and paste it in a folder called copytools.
5. Now go to the command prompt and go to the location of the copytools.
6. Then execute the command android.bat the sdk manager will start.
7. Now update all the plugins you want. It'll update your original folder.
8. After the update delete the copy.

Comment: This worked for me. I think using the command prompt made the difference.

Answer (score 4):

I got mine working by going into the android-sdk\temp folder and extracting the `tools_r22.3-windows.zip` and renaming the current `tools` folder to `tools123` and moved the extracted tools folder to `\android-sdk\`

Comment: I simply extracted the contents of the zip file into the "tools" folder - and the Android SDK indicated the tools as updated to the latest version after a restart. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Close command line & explorer (whatever is blocking java.exe)
- Cut all files & folders from temp folder (android-sdk\temp)
- Paste it to some other folder say (temp_old)
- Run cmd.exe (Run as administrator) and start the process again.
- If still it doesn't work, manually copy tools directory to temp folder & check.

Answer (score 0):

IF USING ANDROID BUNDLE

close the SDK manager and eclipse. From the SDK folder in bundle  goto tools. Copy all files of the tools folder to another folder named toolscopy. Now in cmd navigate to SDK folder then to toolscopy and execute "android.bat". Now the SDK manager will execute and you can update all your updates.
you can delete the toolscopy folder as the tools folder will automatically get updatesd :D

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse and try again it will work.. (After closing eclipse Android SDK Manager window will not close)

or,

Just go to task manager and end the eclipse process and try again it will work..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a very simple way, worked well for me.

1. close eclipse.exe
2. go to your directory containing android-sdks
3. run SDK Manager.exe
4. install required packages
5. close sdk Manager.exe
6. Start eclipse and you are almost there
7. update your ADT plugins by visiting Help menu in eclipse and then Check for Updates
8. in case if it doesn't (which it didn't in my case remove the old versions of plugins manually) work and install them again from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Resolve that

1. Close the Eclipse

2.Run the SDK Manager

3.Now update the packages

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Then go to temp folder extract "tools_r24.0.2-windows.zip" copy "tools" folder from extracted folder and then paste it inside "sdk" folder.(or override on tools folder) :)

Answer (score 0):

100 % working...

1. close eclipse.exe
2. go to your directory containing android-sdks
3. run SDK Manager.exe
4. install required packages
5. close sdk Manager.exe
6. Start eclipse and you are almost there
7. update your ADT plugins by visiting Help menu in eclipse and then Check for Updates
8. Restart your computer.

Answer (score -1):

If you install SDK with eclipse in execution this error will go occur. For you resolve this problem, you should have stop the eclipse application.

Comment: If you read my entire question you will see that I wrote "I have tried closing Eclipse and running SDK Manager from the file directory, same issue", also this issue has been resolved. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this using "unlocker" by emptyloop to unlock the directory without having to kill java.exe using the task manager.

Comment: Could add a little more details. A link to the software and perhaps a screenshot would suffice.

Comment: that didn't do it for me ... unlocker indicated 'no handle' for java.exe.