# Updated SDK Manager causes loads of errors

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Couple of days ago I updated my SDK Manager. I used to be on API 8 and now I added API 11 and API 16 plus all the other updates for SDK Tools:

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/926/fka9.jpg
(Also, note that error at the bottom: [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified.)

Updating was extremely painful. I had to unzip all the downloaded files and copy them over existing ones. Update also broke a lot of my projects. First I had to redo all the imports for google-play-services-lib, but now there's a plethora of other problems. There's the standard import R problem. I guess it's caused by errors in XML files. Which btw haven't been there before this update. Errors like No resource identifier found for attribute 'showDividers' in linear layout or errors in style.xml

Why are these errors happening? Android manifest is still unchanged and minSDK version is set to 8 (targetSDK is set to 17). Project properties are also set to Android 2.2 as seen in this image:

http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9738/da6b.jpg

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you updated the adt..

Comment: Nope. How do I do that? Btw, I'm using Eclipse Juno version.

Comment: ok im writing the answere..

Comment: I did, but it failed to install. Just like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587478/sdk-manager-failed-to-install-java-exe-locking-directory

Comment: at least try my answere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update Adt.

**1)** Go to help.

**2)** Then go to install new software.

**3)** The updates will be shown here so check all the check boxes and click next and after the completion

**4)** Restart Eclipse..

**5)** Enjoy....

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes. I suppose this is it: http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/1280/dff9.jpg

Comment: Nope, I'm not using it. I've updated it. The errors are still there.
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showDividers' in package 'android'
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

Comment: Only these 2 errors now: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/1228/w5c8.jpg and http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/1357/mj9b.jpg

Comment: I switched target to Android 4.1 in Properties and now it's all working. Thanks a lot! I set it to Answered.