# Android SDK not updating.

Tags: android, updating, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to update my Android SDK and it keeps failing. I tried running it as Administrator but it keep failing to "rename" the folder". here is there prompt it gives

[image: Other Programs using it]

Which is weird because i turned off my anti-virus like it said and closed all windows except it. yes it still give this window.

the other screen i get is this

[image: SDK Log]

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDK Manager failed to install 'java.exe' locking directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587478/sdk-manager-failed-to-install-java-exe-locking-directory)

Comment: have you tried closing the sdk manager and it's directories completely, and then re-opening and re-trying? I know they shuffled some stuff around for the recent SDK tools updates.

Comment: i have. i did a restart just incase something was using it and i didnt know but it still gives me the same message

Comment: Also John this is a different problem as it says nothing about locking and the solution in that question did not work here